# Launch iOS Youtube app with playlist

Tags: ios, youtube, playlist

Youtube application can be launched using the youtube:// url scheme. Is there a way I could pass the playlist ID to it so that upon hitting url, youtube would launch with playlist. I have tried these with no luck

youtube://http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=someID.
youtube://list=someID.
youtube://playlist?list=someID.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work!

```
youtube://{VIDEO_ID}?list={PLAYLIST_ID}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't [look possible](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/YouTubeLinks.html) with the iOS SDK.